# uploade multiple image using restkit?

Tags: ios, restkit

I am using restkit library for REST Services.I don't know how to send Multiple images,i can send single image, i don't have idea.

```
[LoadingView showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window]];
    NSString *url=@"/upload";
    NSDictionary *dic=@{@"userId":[self.appUtil getDataForKey:@"USERID"]};
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] multipartFormRequestWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:url parameters:dic constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

        [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgProfile.image)
                                    name:@"file"
                                fileName:@"photo.png"
                                mimeType:@"image/png"];
    }];

    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
        NSString* userString=operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString;
        NSLog(@"%@",userString);
        NSError* error = nil;
        [LoadingView removeFromView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window]];
        StatusInnner *state=[[StatusInnner alloc]initWithString:userString error:&error];
        if (state!=nil) {
            if ([state.status.status isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
                [self.appUtil createSimpleAlertView:self title:string_title_success
                                            message:state.status.msg];
            }else{
            [self.appUtil createSimpleAlertView:self title:string_title_success
                                        message:state.status.msg];
        }
        }
```

Comment: check my answer and if you need any help then let me know

Answer (score 0):

First add all your imagedata in array.After that create a loop on formdata like this

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] multipartFormRequestWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:url parameters:dic constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    for (int i=0;i<yourImagesArray.count;i++)
    {
      UIImage *image = [yourImagesArray objectAtIndex:i];
     [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
                                        name:@"file"
                                    fileName:@"photo.png"
                                    mimeType:@"image/png"];
    }
 }];
```

Comment: i will check and let you know,